# How can I install Ubuntu in a computer without an OS?

Tags: installation

I got a computer from my office and ordered IT to wipe it all from Windows OS. Now how can I get Ubuntu OS on this computer?

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple. Just download Ubuntu from this official website.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
Burn it to a DVD.
Insert it and change the boot device order in BIOS to DVD drive.
Now boot from the DVD and follow this link to install Ubuntu from DVD.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Comment: You can also use USB stick to install Ubuntu. For more details on that browse Askubuntu.